# How to get the output of a jsp file in an HTML text field

Tags: html, jsp

**index.html**

```
<form action="add.jsp">
first number-<input type="text" name="n1"><br>
second number-<input type="text" name="n2"><br>
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"><br>
result-<input type="text">
</form>
```

**add.jsp**

```
<body>
<%
int a,b,c;
a=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("n1"));
b=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("n2"));
c=a+b;
%>
</body>
```

How can I put the value of `c` in the "result" textfield in the `index.html` page?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I will suggest not to use `scriptlets` in a jsp. Jsp is used in view layer for serving the processed outcome, put all your logic in a `servlet` instead of this approach.
Simpler way to do this:

Change the form tag of your index.jsp to:

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/demoCalculator">
```

Now create a Servlet: (You need to map this servlet in your web.xml file with a url-pattern "demoCalculator")

```
import javax.servlet.http.*;  
import javax.servlet.*;  
public class DemoServlet extends HttpServlet{  
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)  
    throws ServletException  
    {  

        int a=0,b=0,c=0;
        a=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("n1"));
        b=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("n2"));
        c=a+b;
        request.setAttribute("result", c);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Map the servlet in `web.xml` with url-pattern "demoCalculator"

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DemoServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/demoCalculator/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Use a jsp page as your index.jsp and keep the result like this:

```
result-<input type="text" value='<c:out value="${requestScope.result}"/>' >
```